# How do I remove outliers using IQR in pyspark?

Tags: pyspark

I know how to remove outliers with iqr using pandas. But now i'm trying to learn pyspark. I have done some searching online, but most of them only flag outliers with 'yes' and 'no', and does not proceed to remove them. Additionally, I also dont understand the code they are writing.

I have also tried it out a bit by myself but to no avail. Ultimately, I dont know where to start.

Here's an example dataframe

```
+----------+---------+--------------+---------------+----------------------+------------+
|      town|flat_type|    flat_model|remaining_lease|floor_area_sqm_imputed|resale_price|
+----------+---------+--------------+---------------+----------------------+------------+
|ANG MO KIO|   2 ROOM|      Improved|            736|                  44.0|    232000.0|
|ANG MO KIO|   3 ROOM|New Generation|            727|                  67.0|    250000.0|
|ANG MO KIO|   3 ROOM|New Generation|            749|                  67.0|    262000.0|
|ANG MO KIO|   3 ROOM|New Generation|            745|                  68.0|    265000.0|
|ANG MO KIO|   3 ROOM|New Generation|            749|                  67.0|    265000.0|
|ANG MO KIO|   3 ROOM|New Generation|            756|                  68.0|    275000.0|
|ANG MO KIO|   3 ROOM|New Generation|            738|                  68.0|    280000.0|
|ANG MO KIO|   3 ROOM|New Generation|            700|                  67.0|    285000.0|
|ANG MO KIO|   3 ROOM|New Generation|            738|                  68.0|    285000.0|
|ANG MO KIO|   3 ROOM|New Generation|            736|                  67.0|    285000.0|
+----------+---------+--------------+---------------+----------------------+------------+
```

I plan on doing removals for `floor_area_sqm_imputed` so i dont need code that assumes there are multiple columns.

Any help appreciated. I know it sounds like I just want answers instead of searching for myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [percentile_approx](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.percentile_approx.html) Spark SQL function to compute quantile 1 and quantile 3 and filter records in this range.

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame(data=[["ANG MO KIO","2 ROOM","Improved",736,44.0,232000.0],["ANG MO KIO","3 ROOM","New Generation",727,67.0,250000.0],["ANG MO KIO","3 ROOM","New Generation",749,67.0,262000.0],["ANG MO KIO","3 ROOM","New Generation",745,68.0,265000.0],["ANG MO KIO","3 ROOM","New Generation",749,67.0,265000.0],["ANG MO KIO","3 ROOM","New Generation",756,68.0,275000.0],["ANG MO KIO","3 ROOM","New Generation",738,68.0,280000.0],["ANG MO KIO","3 ROOM","New Generation",700,67.0,285000.0],["ANG MO KIO","3 ROOM","New Generation",738,68.0,285000.0],["ANG MO KIO","3 ROOM","New Generation",736,67.0,285000.0]], schema=["town","flat_type","flat_model","remaining_lease","floor_area_sqm_imputed","resale_price"])

qtr_map = df.select( \
                    F.expr("percentile_approx(floor_area_sqm_imputed, 0.25) as Q1"), \
                    F.expr("percentile_approx(floor_area_sqm_imputed, 0.75) as Q3") \
             ) \
             .collect()[0] \
             .asDict()

df = df.filter( \
               (F.col("floor_area_sqm_imputed") >= qtr_map["Q1"]) \
               & (F.col("floor_area_sqm_imputed") <= qtr_map["Q3"]) \
        )
```

Output:

```
+----------+---------+--------------+---------------+----------------------+------------+
|      town|flat_type|    flat_model|remaining_lease|floor_area_sqm_imputed|resale_price|
+----------+---------+--------------+---------------+----------------------+------------+
|ANG MO KIO|   3 ROOM|New Generation|            727|                  67.0|    250000.0|
|ANG MO KIO|   3 ROOM|New Generation|            749|                  67.0|    262000.0|
|ANG MO KIO|   3 ROOM|New Generation|            745|                  68.0|    265000.0|
|ANG MO KIO|   3 ROOM|New Generation|            749|                  67.0|    265000.0|
|ANG MO KIO|   3 ROOM|New Generation|            756|                  68.0|    275000.0|
|ANG MO KIO|   3 ROOM|New Generation|            738|                  68.0|    280000.0|
|ANG MO KIO|   3 ROOM|New Generation|            700|                  67.0|    285000.0|
|ANG MO KIO|   3 ROOM|New Generation|            738|                  68.0|    285000.0|
|ANG MO KIO|   3 ROOM|New Generation|            736|                  67.0|    285000.0|
+----------+---------+--------------+---------------+----------------------+------------+
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. the code works wonderfully. Thank you very much!